# REST resources are not available in magento

Tags: magento, rest, magento-1.7

For using magento rest api I have done the following things.

**In windows**

- installed magento 1.7 CE with oauth(checked in phpinfo).
- created user roles and for guest user granted all permissions.
- later tried to access the rest resources via the URL

  `http://localhost:8036/magento/index.php/api/products/?type=rest`
  `http://localhost:8036/magento/api/products/?type=rest
  http://localhost:8036/magento/api/rest/products/`

  none of them worked. What can I do now? Any kind of help is appreciated. 
  I have followed all the magento guidelies for REST.

**In Ubuntu**

- done the same settings
- while accessing the rest resource via

  http://10.211.20.26/magento/api/rest/products/

  > Not Found
  >
  > The requested URL /magento/api/rest/products/ was not found on this server.

there are products in both of my magento installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your rewriting is broken. I assume you are running Apache HTTPd, so please check .htaccess in the root of Magento installation and make sure your rewriting works. You can do it by uncommenting the corresponding lines. Please add logging to rewrite engine using RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives.

Comment: At last I have fixed it by changing the .htaccess file
there  "Order allow,deny"

<Directory "C:/xampp/apps/magento/htdocs/app">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all

</Directory>

Comment: I'm having this same problem. lighthouse's comment did not work for me. I have the original `.htaccess`. Seems rewrite is working. If you're able to expand further on your answer, such as how to add RewriteLog or RewriteLogLevel, it'd be much appreciated. Virtual host is being used if that's relevant.